# How to detect user interaction with google map Google map JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use fitBounds to update the area a map views, based on new GeoJson data. As soon as a user zooms or drags the map I want to disable the automatic "fitBounds" functionality.

Is there general way of detecting that user interaction caused a change in the viewport?

Thanks so much, for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only event that will fire "*as soon as a user zooms or drags the map*" is the `bounds_changed` event.

You can try all events here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

And you can refer to the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {

    // Do what you want here...
});
```

Comment: But the event doesn't only fire when the user zooms or drags a map - it also fires when you set the bounds (or zoom, or center) from code, so can't be used to disambiguate user interaction from programmatic changes.